# How can I get guest user order list by email using rest API "rest/V1/orders" using searchCriteria?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.5, magento2-4-5

How can I get guest user order list by email using rest API "rest/V1/orders" using searchCriteria ?

Version:-- Magento 2.4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter on "customer_is_guest", here is an example:

```
GET <magento_host>/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=customer_email&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=<guest_user_email>&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][field]=customer_is_guest&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][value]=1&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][condition_type]=eq
```

Do not forget to replace <magento_host> with the base URL of your Magento 2 store and <guest_user_email> with the desired email address.

Answer (score 1):

**Create below custom code**

Create file :app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/webapi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/orders" method="GET">
            <service class="Vendor\Module\Api\GustordersInterface" method="getGustOrder"/>
            <resources>
                <resource ref="anonymous" />
            </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Create file :app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Vendor\Module\Api\GustordersInterface" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Gustorders" />
</config>
```

Create file :app/code/Vendor/Module/Api/GustordersInterface.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Api;

/**
 * orders information acquirer interface
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
interface GustordersInterface
{
    
    /**
     * Get orders information for the store.
     *
     * @param string $email_id
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     * @return \Magento\Directory\Api\Data\CountryInformationInterface
     */
    public function getGustOrder();
}
```

Create file :app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Gustorders.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

class Gustorders implements \Vendor\Module\GustordersInterface
{


 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
    ) 
    {
        $this->orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
    }

    public function getOrderCollection()
    {
       $email_id = $_GET['email_id'];

        $orderCollecion = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToSelect('*');
        $orderCollecion->addAttributeToFilter('customer_email', $email_id);

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($orderCollecion->getData());
        echo "</pre>";
        die('test');
    }

}
```

Test in postman : https://extample.com/rest/V1/orders?email_id=abc@gmail.com

Comment: I want to use order repository instead of CollectionFactory